# Возможно ли сгенерировать файл (.docx) из данных добавленных через веб-формы Битрикс 1с?

Tags: php, битрикс

Создал Веб-форму с кучей полей. При её заполнении данные сохраняются в базу данных, так же их можно посмотреть на странице результата формы. Можно ли сгенерировать вордовский документ по определённому шаблону и заполнить его данными из формы, а затем скачать?

То есть человек заполнил форму (внес какие то условные данные), а админ нажал кнопку скачать и с сайта загрузился документ (например договор), который имеет определённый шаблон и в определённых местах вставлены данные которые пользователь внёс через веб-форму.

Получится ли осуществить такое с помощью Битрикса?

Comment: Ответы на оба вопроса - да, возможно.

Comment: А как? Есть какой то компонент для этого? В каком направлении копать? Я нашёл только нечто подобное в Магазин > Заказы > Печать заказа, но я так понял это немного не туда

Comment: Например вот, или еще погуглить и взять не самую первую ссылку в поисковике https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: А, ну получается сделать это с помощью PHP нужно а не Битрикса. Я просто думал может в битриксе для этого какой то модуль есть или компонент. Я даже не догадался почему то так сказать от простого пойти)) Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Вроде ответил в прошлом комментарие что можно брать не первую ссылку гугла.... https://blog.bedrosova.ru/2019/07/08/bitrix24_document_designer/